# How do I stretch the slideshow/Carousel in terms of height?

Tags: html, css

HTML and Javascript and I am unable to increase my height of my slideshow/Carousel.

I have tried changing the height of the #bigbigcontainer and the .slideshow-container but it still doesn't work.

This is what I am trying to get: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv7cW.png)

This is what I have so far (in this context the javascript is irrelevant):

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
html{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
.topnav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    flex: 1;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
  
 
  


body{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient( rgb(35, 166, 252), white);
   
  }

* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none;
           
}
img {vertical-align: middle;}


#bigbigcontainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;

  
}


/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
 position: relative;
 width: 50%;


  
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
 
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: larger;
 
  
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
 
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  position: relative;
  right: 25%;

  
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="mypresent.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="mypresent.js"></script>
    <h1>MY PRESENT</h1>
    <div class="topnav">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a>
          <a href="mypast.html">My Past</a>
          <a href="mypresent.html">My Present</a>
          <a href="myfuture.html">My Future</a>
          <a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="bigbigcontainer">
    <div class="slideshow-container">

      
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
        <img src="classphoto.jpg" style="width:100%">
        
      </div>
      
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
        <img src="Code.JPG" style="width:100%">
        
      </div>
      
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      

      
      </div>
      <br>
      
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
        
      </div>
    
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment it looks as though you are fixing the width of an img at 100% (i.e. half the whole thing) and so it will take up whatever space it needs to show the height of a particular img, which depends on its aspect ratio.

So, if you want the height to be fixed rather than the width you can do that, but in either case you run the risk of only part of the img showing if it is too big in the other dimension.

It sounds as though you want every img to cover the full area, in which case try `object-fit: cover`.

If you are concerned that the whole img should always be seen, whether it fills the whole height or width or not, then investigate `object-fit: contain` instead.

If you want the img to have 100% of the height, without the top and bottom getting cropped, then set `height: 100%` and `width: auto` and deal with possible overflow (which will lead to cropping).